# Using typeahead and ajax in a AngularJS app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am having issues using Bootstrap-UI's typeahead control with dynamic data (data fetched from ajax call).

The response in my service looks a bit like this `[{id:1, text:'somebrand'},{id:2, text:'something'}]`

The HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="result" min-length="2" typeahead="brand.id as brand.text for brand in brands($viewValue)" style="display:block">
```

And in my controller I retrieve the content like this:

```
$scope.brands = function(brandName){
        $http.post('/brands/getbrandsviewmodel', { query : brandName}).then(function(response){
            return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
        });
    };
```

The issue I run into is an error in Bootstrap-UI like this:

```
 Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at http://localhost:3000/assets/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js?body=1:2749:24
```

When I debug into the Bootstrap-UI code I see that the error occures here, and that matches is undefined:

```
//it might happen that several async queries were in progress if a user were typing fast
          //but we are interested only in responses that correspond to the current view value
          if (inputValue === modelCtrl.$viewValue) {
            if (matches.length > 0) {....
```

My initial reaction is that Bootstrap-UI's typeahead isn't aware when the data is retrieved, but I don't know why, since I am using promises?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to actually *return* a promise from your `brands` function. Try this:

```
$scope.brands = function(brandName){
       return $http.post('/brands/getbrandsviewmodel', { query : brandName})
                     .then(function(response){
                        return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
                      });
    };
```