# AngularJS UI Bootstrap typeahead with ajax using Coffeescript

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

My question is very similar to [this post 'Using typeahead and ajax in a AngularJS app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025738/using-typeahead-and-ajax-in-a-angularjs-app)

Coffeescript:

```
  $scope.tradingPartners = (searchOn) ->
    console.log("Searching on #{searchOn}")
    $.getJSON("../tp/tpLookupAdmin", {term: searchOn, max: 20}, (response)->
        response)
```

Generates Javascript:

```
$scope.tradingPartners = function(searchOn) {
      console.log("Searching on " + searchOn);
      return $.getJSON("../tp/tpLookupAdmin", {
        term: searchOn,
        max: 20
      }, function(response) {
        return response;
      });
    };
```

Using it:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="testScript.sender" typeahead="sender as sender.label for sender in tradingPartners($viewValue)"
```

So whats wrong? ...

The getJSON call is made just fine, the results look good but the typeahead does not do anything.  If I put hardcoded values in as the return from the function it works just fine.

Now I know the getJSON is not just returning an object array, and doing

```
$.getJSON("../tp/tpLookupAdmin", {term: searchOn, max: 20}, (response)->
        response).responseJSON
```

gives undefined.

Example hardcoded json that works:

```
[{"id":"1","label":"test1"},{"id":"2","label":"test2"}]
```

I'm missing something simple here...

Edit (from kju answer):

Now gen'd JS is

```
$scope.tradingPartners = function(searchOn) {
  return $http.post("../tp/tpLookupAdmin?term=" + searchOn).then(function(response) {
    return limitToFilter(response, 15);
  });
};
```

But its still not working...

Answer (score 4):

The question you are referencing had already all the answers you need, so yours is really not a good question.

The lookup function must return either an array or a (AngularJS-style) promise. What you return is the return value of $.getJSON which is neither. The callback function in your code will return a array but to nowhere. It will not end up in Angular. This can't be helped because you are making an asynchronous HTTP request here. When the request returns, your lookup function has long returned before. Therefore you need to return a promise. AngularJS knows how to handle this promise and process the deferred data.

As I said, the other question and its accepted answer already has everything in it. Get rid of $.getJSOn and use the $http service from Angular as it is shown there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've made changes, I think the JS looks good but still the typeahead doesn't work...will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with using select2.  I think its a cleaner more consistent approach in my case anyway.

```
<input ui-select2="tpSearch" ng-model="testScript.sender" class="input-xlarge"/>
```

CoffeeScript:

```
$scope.tpSearch =
    placeholder: "Type to search..."
    minimumInputLength: 2
    ajax:
      url: "../tp/tpLookupPaged"
      quietMillis: 100
      data: (term, page) ->
        term: term # query params 
        page: page
        max: 10
      results: (data, page) ->  
         more = (page * 10) < data.total
         results: data.results, more: more
```

Implementing infinite scroll was a breeze.

Make sure your JSON returns an array containing id and text or you'll have to write a custom formatter function for select2 (easy enough anyway)